# Why doesn't getValue() function work for a HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hash, hashmap

I was solving a question on finding the duplicates in an array. I made use of a HashMap. but the getValue() function gave me an error when I included it within an IF condition.

```
for(Map.Entry m : hm.entrySet())
{  
   if(m.getValue() > 1)
   {
      System.out.println(m.getKey());
   }  
}
```

however it seems to work fine when I used typecasting

```
for(Map.Entry m : hm.entrySet())
{ 
    int count = (int)m.getValue();  
    if(count > 1)
    {
        System.out.println(m.getKey());
    }  
}
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: what are those K, V defining your map

Comment: What error was thrown?

Comment: HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

Comment: definition is irrelevant because they are using raw types as the reference type of `m` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Why did this happen?*...

because you are using an Entry with raw types...

your `Map.Entry` must match the map type in the generic type K,V

example: if you define a map of the form

```
Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

then you can do

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> m : hm.entrySet()) {
    if (m.getValue() > 1) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey());
    }
}
```

bacause doing this `m.getValue() > 1` automatically unbox the Integer into an int making valid the comparison  against the literal int 1